# Difference between export default and export { default }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've been using named export and default export extensively in my React and I came across these 2 similar syntaxes.

`export default from './Button';`

`export { default } from './Button';`

Can somebody tell me what is their difference? It seems like they are doing the same thing with the former VSCode `Go To Definition` function not working on the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the difference**

There is a huge difference between the two, one is in standard ES6 and the other is yet a proposal.

```
// Standard ES6
export { default } from './Button';
```

This is standard ES6: it is exporting the Default of Button from the current module (without altering the local scope of the current module)

```
// A Proposal
export default from './Button';
```

This is a proposal, and that explains why it does not work at vscode
Here is the proposal https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-default-from (still stage 1)

Basically according to the proposal both should work exactly the same, the proposal is just another more elegant way of writing it - so that it matches how we export default in Standarad ES6.

Look here if you want to see why exactly the author of the proposal made it
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-default-from#common-concerns

**Why they both work**

JavaScript as it is often used today is no longer a mere interpreted language. It is more like a transpiled langauge, where  what we write ( though in JavaScript or something similar) is still not the same that we send for the JS engine.

Now it works for you ( In your Code ) because part of your build system is taking code written with this proposal and transpiling it to standarad ES6. If we were to speak about Babel the most popular JS transpiler, this syntax is enabled with the following plugin    https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-export-default-from.html.

**Should I keep using the proposal**

Preferably no, this is a proposal in state 1, even if Babel - or any other transpiler - makes it work, there is a chance that it never makes it to Standarad JavaScript. And if that happens there will come a time in the future will you will have to re-write that code.

Comment: This is actually what I'm looking for. But since it's in proposals stage, why does the first export statement still work just fine? It doesn't break my code.

Comment: @KelokChan I edited my answer to answer your question in the comment

Answer (score 2):

ES6 provides us to import a module and use it in other files. Strictly speaking in React terms, one can use stateless components in other components by exporting the components from their respective modules and using them in other files.

> ES6 provides two ways to export a module from a file: named export and
>   default export.

**Named Export: (export)**

With named exports, one can have multiple named exports per file. Then import the specific exports they want to be surrounded in braces. The name of the imported module has to be the same as the name of the exported module.

```
// imports
// ex. importing a single named export
import { MyComponent } from "./MyComponent";
// ex. importing multiple named exports
import { MyComponent, MyComponent2 } from "./MyComponent";
// ex. giving a named import a different name by using "as":
import { MyComponent2 as MyNewComponent } from "./MyComponent";
// exports from ./MyComponent.js file
export const MyComponent = () => {}
export const MyComponent2 = () => {}
```

Import all the named exports onto an object:

```
import * as MainComponents from "./MyComponent";
// use MainComponents.MyComponent and MainComponents.MyComponent2
here
```

**Default Export: (export default)**

One can have only one default export per file. When we import we have to specify a name and import like:

```
// import
import MyDefaultComponent from "./MyDefaultExport";
// export
const MyComponent = () => {}
export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiple exports from a file, you should go with `Named exports`, which you can import using `{}`. If there is only one export, ideally you should go with `Default export`.

Please refer [Javascript Exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) for further understanding. Please note `default` is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910) is a nice article to make clear de differences between them, but the biggest difference is that you could only have one `Default Export` per file, as:

```
export Button from './Button';
```

And in cases where you need to have multiple items exported you should go with the `Named Export`, as:

```
export { ButtonAccept, ButtonCancel, ButtonInfo } from './Button';
```

Answer (score 0):

For the documentation, you can refer to link shared by sSD and Alberto and also answer of Clue. I have created an example for understanding it better and to help you as well.

Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-surf-o78v1

Code if the link expires:

**App Structure is:**

```
src
├── index.js
├── button                   
│   ├── index.js          
│   ├── Button.js
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Button, { FillButton } from "./button";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button />
      <FillButton />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**src/button/Button.js**

```
import React from "react";

export const FillButton = () => {
  return <button style={{ background: "aquamarine" }}>Awesome bossom</button>;
};

const Button = () => {
  return <button>Awesome</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

**src/button/index.js**

```
export { default, FillButton } from "./Button";
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a function called `abc()` is exported from `./Button`

> Can somebody tell me what is their difference?

- The difference is that your first `export` re-exports function `abc` as *unnamed* export so that it can be imported as any `AssignedbyImporterName`:

```js
import AssignedbyImporterName from ...
```

and used as `AssignedbyImporterName`:

```js
AssignedbyImporterName();                       // call function abc()
```

- Your second `export` re-exports `abc` as *named* export under umbrella of an additional unnamed object which acts as a namespace so that it can be imported as any `AssignedbyImporterNamespace`:

```js
import AssignedbyImporterNamespace from ...
```

and used:

```js
AssignedbyImporterNamespace.abc();             // call function abc()
```

Comment: Nah, not correct. Both exports are exporting default exports

Comment: @ehab Yes but the first one re-exports the function `abc` as the default export so it effectively 'looses' its name as any default export. Whereas the second `export` re- exports as default an unnamed object (which doesn't loose its name because it's already unnamed) that has named top-level object key called `abc`

Comment: both are exactly the same, it's just that one is a proposal and the other is standard es6, you can look at my answer where i gave details and links

Answer (score -1):

**If your need is to export multiple objects go with named exports(without default keyword).**

It's easiest to just look at what the three different ES6 import/export styles compile down to in CommonJS.

```
// Three different export styles
export foo;
export default foo;
export = foo;

// The three matching import styles
import {foo} from 'blah';
import foo from 'blah';
import * as foo from 'blah';
```

Roughly compiles to:

```
exports.foo = foo;
exports['default'] = foo;
module.exports = foo;

var foo = require('blah').foo;
var foo = require('blah')['default'];
var foo = require('blah');
```